# Calling GUI in another class from MainGUI class but get blank white frame instead

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm sorry if this question already solved or something because I searched many things but couldn't solve my problem. The thing is, I made a GUI for MainGUI class and want to access another GUI says ClientGUI or ServerGUI from another class but I keep getting blank white frame instead (although the connection status will be connected / functioning properly)

MainGUI.java

```
package chat
/*
 * Notes: This project use source code by Ashish Myles: 
 * https://ashishmyles.com/tutorials/tcpchat/index.html
 */

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class MainGUI 
{
    public MainGUI() 
    {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("ServerClient Chat");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout mainLayout = new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

        Font commonFont = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14);

        mainPanel.setLayout(mainLayout);
        mainPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(120, 0, 0, 0)));

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("ServerClient Chat");
        titleLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        titleLabel.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 20));

        JPanel ipPane = new JPanel();
        ipPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        ipPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 70));
        ipPane.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(300, 70));
        ipPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 70));

        String myIp = "";
        ipcheck checkIp = new ipcheck();

        try 
        {
            myIp = checkIp.ip();
        } 

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JLabel ipLabel = new JLabel("Your IP address is ");
        ipLabel.setFont(commonFont);

        JLabel ipAddress = new JLabel(myIp);
        ipAddress.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));

        ipPane.add(ipLabel);
        ipPane.add(ipAddress);

        JLabel logLabel = new JLabel("Log me in as: ");
        logLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        logLabel.setFont(commonFont);

        JPanel userPane = new JPanel();
        userPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
        userPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(150, 40));
        userPane.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 40));
        userPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 40));

        JRadioButton clientButton = new JRadioButton("Client");
        JRadioButton serverButton = new JRadioButton("Server");

        ButtonGroup userButton = new ButtonGroup();
        userButton.add(clientButton);
        userButton.add(serverButton);

        userPane.add(clientButton);
        userPane.add(serverButton);

        JButton selectButton = new JButton("Select");
        selectButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        selectButton.setFont(commonFont);

        selectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {       
                if(clientButton.isSelected()) 
                {   
                    // ask for username, ip address & port number input
                    String ip, port;
                    ip = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mainFrame, "Input server's IP address", "Input IP address", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                    port = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mainFrame, "Input server's port number", "Input port number", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

                    String ipAddress = ip.toString();
                    int portNum = Integer.parseInt(port);

                    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mainFrame, "You are now connected to Server\nIP Address     :   " + ipAddress + "\nPort Number  :   " + portNum, "Connected", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                    // open ClientGUI interface
                    new ClientGUI(ipAddress, portNum);

                    mainFrame.setVisible(false);
                } 

                else if(serverButton.isSelected()) 
                {   
                    // ask for port number input
                    String port;
                    String myIp = "";
                    ipcheck checkIp = new ipcheck();

                    try 
                    {
                        myIp = checkIp.ip();
                    } 

                    catch (Exception ee) 
                    {
                        ee.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    port = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mainFrame, "Input server's port number", "Input port number", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

                    int portNum = Integer.parseInt(port);

                    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mainFrame, "You are accepting connection from Client\nIP Address     :   " + myIp + "\nPort Number  :   " + portNum, "Connected", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                    // open ServerGUI interface
                    new ServerGUI(portNum);
                    mainFrame.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });

        mainPanel.add(titleLabel);
        mainPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 20)));
        mainPanel.add(ipPane);
        mainPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 60)));
        mainPanel.add(logLabel);
        mainPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
        mainPanel.add(userPane);
        mainPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
        mainPanel.add(selectButton);

        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);

        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        ipPane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        userPane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        clientButton.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        serverButton.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        mainFrame.setSize(700, 500);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MainGUI();
    }
}
```

ServerGUI.java

```
package chat;
/*
 * Notes: This project use source code by Ashish Myles: 
 * https://ashishmyles.com/tutorials/tcpchat/index.html
 */

import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ServerGUI implements Runnable 
{
    // Connect status constants
    public final static int NULL = 0;
    public final static int DISCONNECTED = 1;
    public final static int DISCONNECTING = 2;
    public final static int BEGIN_CONNECT = 3;
    public final static int CONNECTED = 4;

    // Other constants
    public final static String statusMessages[] = 
        {
            " Error! Could not connect!", " Disconnected",
            " Disconnecting...", " Connecting...", " Connected"
        };
    public final static ServerGUI tcpObj = new ServerGUI();
    public final static String END_CHAT_SESSION = new Character((char)0).toString(); // Indicates the end of a session
    public static Font commonFont = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14);

    // Connection state info
    public static String hostIP = "localhost";
    public static int port = 1700;
    public static int connectionStatus = DISCONNECTED;
    public static boolean isHost = true;
    public static String statusString = statusMessages[connectionStatus];
    public static StringBuffer toAppend = new StringBuffer("");
    public static StringBuffer toSend = new StringBuffer("");

    // Various GUI components and info
    public static JFrame mainFrame = null;
    public static JTextArea messageBox = null;
    public static JPanel statusBar = null;
    public static JLabel statusField = null;
    public static JLabel status = null;
    public static JLabel statusLabel = null;
    public static JTextField statusColor = null;
    public static JButton homeButton = null;
    public static JButton disconnectButton = null;
    public static JButton sendButton = null;
    public static JButton replyButton = null;

    // TCP Components
    public static ServerSocket hostServer = null;
    public static Socket socket = null;
    public static BufferedReader in = null;
    public static PrintWriter out = null;

    // Initialize all the GUI components and display the frame
    private static void initGUI() 
    {   
        // Set up the status bar
        statusField = new JLabel();
        statusField.setText(statusMessages[DISCONNECTED]);
        statusColor = new JTextField(1);
        statusColor.setBackground(Color.red);
        statusColor.setEditable(false);
        statusBar = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        statusBar.add(statusColor, BorderLayout.WEST);
        statusBar.add(statusField, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // First Panel
        homeButton = new JButton("Home");
        disconnectButton = new JButton("Disconnect");

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
        firstPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(firstPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        JPanel topLeftPanel = new JPanel();
        topLeftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topLeftPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        statusLabel = new JLabel("Status: ");
        status = new JLabel("");

        statusLabel.setFont(commonFont);
        status.setFont(commonFont);

        topLeftPanel.add(statusLabel);
        topLeftPanel.add(status);
        topLeftPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(2, 0)));

        JPanel topRightPanel = new JPanel();
        topRightPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topRightPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        topRightPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 40)));
        topRightPanel.add(disconnectButton);
        topRightPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));
        topRightPanel.add(homeButton);


        firstPanel.add(topLeftPanel);
        firstPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(390, 120)));
        firstPanel.add(topRightPanel);

        // Second Panel

        sendButton = new JButton("Send");
        replyButton = new JButton("Reply");

        JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
        secondPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(secondPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        secondPanel.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);

        sendButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,50));
        replyButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,50));

        secondPanel.add(sendButton);
        secondPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(15, 0)));
        secondPanel.add(replyButton);
        secondPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(450, 0)));

        // Third Panel
        JPanel thirdPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        messageBox = new JTextArea();
//      messageBox.setLineWrap(true);
        messageBox.setEditable(false);

        JScrollPane textBox = new JScrollPane(messageBox, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        textBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 400));

        thirdPanel.add(textBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        thirdPanel.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);          

        mainPanel.add(firstPanel);
        mainPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100, 0)));
        mainPanel.add(secondPanel);
        mainPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(500, 10)));
        mainPanel.add(thirdPanel);

        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        firstPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        secondPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        thirdPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        topLeftPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        topRightPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {   
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                JFrame createFrame = new JFrame("Input message");

                JPanel createPanel = new JPanel();

                createPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 20)));

                JLabel createLabel = new JLabel("Input message: ");
                createPanel.add(createLabel);

                createPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 50)));

                JTextArea textInput = new JTextArea();
                textInput.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 250));
                textInput.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600, 250));
                textInput.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 250));

                createPanel.add(textInput);

                JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

                JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
                JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");

                sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {   
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                    {
                        String s = textInput.getText();
                        if (!s.equals("")) 
                        {
                            appendToChatBox("Server: " + s + "\n");
                            textInput.selectAll();

                            // Send the string
                            sendString(s);
                        }

                        createFrame.dispose();
                    }
                });

                cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        createFrame.dispose();
                    }
                });

                buttonPanel.add(sendButton);
                buttonPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5, 0)));
                buttonPanel.add(cancelButton);

                createPanel.add(buttonPanel);

                createFrame.add(createPanel);

                buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                createPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                createFrame.setSize(700, 400);
                createFrame.setResizable(false);
                createFrame.setVisible(true);
                createFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(mainFrame);
            }
        });

        replyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {   
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {

            }
        });

        disconnectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {   
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mainFrame, "Do you want to disconnect?", "Disconnect", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

                if(option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
                {
                    changeStatusNTS(DISCONNECTING, true);
                }

                else
                    return;
            }
        });

        homeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {   
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                new MainGUI();
                mainFrame.dispose();            
                return;
            }
        });

        // Set up the main frame
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Server");
        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//      mainFrame.setContentPane(mainPane);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setSize(800,630); // 800,650
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // The thread-safe way to change the GUI components while
    // changing state
    private static void changeStatusTS(int newConnectStatus, boolean noError) 
    {
        // Change state if valid state
        if (newConnectStatus != NULL) 
        {
            connectionStatus = newConnectStatus;
        }

        // If there is no error, display the appropriate status message
        if (noError) 
        {
            statusString = statusMessages[connectionStatus];
        }

        // Otherwise, display error message
        else 
        {
            statusString = statusMessages[NULL];
        }

        // Call the run() routine (Runnable interface) on the
        // error-handling and GUI-update thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(tcpObj);
    }

    // The non-thread-safe way to change the GUI components while
    // changing state
    private static void changeStatusNTS(int newConnectStatus, boolean noError) 
    {
        // Change state if valid state
        if (newConnectStatus != NULL) 
        {
            connectionStatus = newConnectStatus;
        }

        // If there is no error, display the appropriate status message
        if (noError) 
        {
            statusString = statusMessages[connectionStatus];
        }

        // Otherwise, display error message
        else 
        {
            statusString = statusMessages[NULL];
        }

        // Call the run() routine (Runnable interface) on the
        // current thread
        tcpObj.run();
    }

    // Thread-safe way to append to the chat box
    private static void appendToChatBox(String s) 
    {
        synchronized (toAppend) 
        {
            toAppend.append(s);
        }
    }

    // Add text to send-buffer
    private static void sendString(String s) 
    {
        synchronized (toSend) 
        {
            toSend.append(s + "\n");
        }
    }

    // Cleanup for disconnect
    private static void cleanUp() 
    {
        try 
        {
            if (hostServer != null) 
            {
                hostServer.close();
                hostServer = null;
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e) { hostServer = null; }

        try 
        {
            if (socket != null) 
            {
                socket.close();
                socket = null;
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e) { socket = null; }

        try 
        {
            if (in != null) 
            {
                in.close();
                in = null;
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e) { in = null; }

        if (out != null) 
        {
            out.close();
            out = null;
        }
    }

    // Checks the current state and sets the enables/disables
    // accordingly
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        switch (connectionStatus) 
        {
            case DISCONNECTED:
                homeButton.setEnabled(true);
                disconnectButton.setEnabled(false);
                sendButton.setEnabled(false);
                replyButton.setEnabled(false);
                status.setText("Disconnected");
                status.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
                statusColor.setBackground(Color.red);
                break;

            case DISCONNECTING:
                homeButton.setEnabled(false);
                disconnectButton.setEnabled(false);
                sendButton.setEnabled(false);
                replyButton.setEnabled(false);
                status.setText("Disconnecting...");
                status.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
                statusColor.setBackground(Color.orange);
                break;

            case CONNECTED:
                homeButton.setEnabled(false);
                disconnectButton.setEnabled(true);
                sendButton.setEnabled(true);
                replyButton.setEnabled(true);
                status.setText("Connected");
                status.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
                statusColor.setBackground(Color.green);
                break;

            case BEGIN_CONNECT:
                homeButton.setEnabled(false);
                disconnectButton.setEnabled(false);
                sendButton.setEnabled(true);
                replyButton.setEnabled(true);
                status.setText("Connecting...");
                status.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
                statusColor.setBackground(Color.orange);
                break;
        }

        // Make sure that the button/text field states are consistent
        // with the internal states
        statusField.setText(statusString);
        messageBox.append(toAppend.toString());
        toAppend.setLength(0);

        mainFrame.repaint();
    }

    public ServerGUI(int portNum)
    {
        String s;

        initGUI();

        changeStatusNTS(BEGIN_CONNECT, true);

        while (true) 
        {
            try 
            { 
                // Poll every ~10 ms
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }

            catch (InterruptedException e) {}

            switch (connectionStatus) 
            {
                case BEGIN_CONNECT:
                    try 
                    {
                        hostServer = new ServerSocket(portNum);
                        socket = hostServer.accept();

                        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                        changeStatusTS(CONNECTED, true);
                    }

                    // If error, clean up and output an error message
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        cleanUp();
                        changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTED, false);
                    }

                    break;

                case CONNECTED:
                    try 
                    {
                        // Send data
                        if (toSend.length() != 0) 
                        {
                            out.print(toSend); out.flush();
                            toSend.setLength(0);
                            changeStatusTS(NULL, true);
                        }

                        // Receive data
                        if (in.ready()) 
                        {
                            s = in.readLine();
                            if ((s != null) &&  (s.length() != 0)) 
                            {
                                // Check if it is the end of a transmission
                                if (s.equals(END_CHAT_SESSION)) 
                                {
                                    changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTING, true);
                                }

                                // Otherwise, receive what text
                                else 
                                {
                                    appendToChatBox("Client: " + s + "\n");
                                    changeStatusTS(NULL, true);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {   
                        cleanUp();
                        changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTED, false);
                    }

                    break;

                case DISCONNECTING:
                    // Tell other chatter to disconnect as well
                    out.print(END_CHAT_SESSION); out.flush();

                    // Clean up (close all streams/sockets)
                    cleanUp();
                    changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTED, true);
                    break;

                default: break; // do nothing
            }
        }
    }

    public ServerGUI()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

ipcheck.java (for checking the ip address)

```
package chat;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ipcheck {

    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
        return;
    }

    public String ip() throws Exception
    {
        String ip;

        InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); 
        ip = localhost.getHostAddress().trim();

        return ip;
    }
}
```

I skipped ClientGUI since it will be the same with ServerGUI with only change the socket thing in case CONNECT.

Please help me solve the blank white frame showed when using select button in MainGUI to call the ServerGUI, thank you :)

Comment: have you debugged your code? Have you checked for error messages? have you tried adding error logs to your catch blocks?

Comment: I run the MainGUI, it run properly, showed all the components in the MainGUI. But after entering the port number to call ServerGUI, it shows blank frame with no error log/message

Comment: If I call the ServerGUI using new ServerGUI(1234); in public static void main of MainGUI, it will show the ServerGUI properly too

Comment: The try catch blocks only used for getting the IP address, I think it shouldn't caused any problem with calling the ServerGUI

Comment: I need to call the serverGUI using specified port number inputted in the MainGUI, that's why I need to solve the white blank frame problem. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Please... Anyone that can help me?